# Visual Studio MySQL no defined at runtime

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, mysql-connector

I've been given a couple VS solutions to replicate a build on my system. I've updated all the needed references, including the connection string and once I tell VS2012 to build I get no errors.

The weird thing is once I tell 'Run', the app won't load and I get MySQL related errors in terms of, for example, 'MySQLConnection is not defined' or 'MySQLCommand is not defined'.

On "code view" I can tell on the MySQL Go to definition and object browser opens up perfectly, so I can't figure what is the problem with this thing.

How can I solve this?

Best Regards,
Celso Santos

#### EDIT:

By popular demand (not really popular, but you get the point :P ), here is a sample of the code:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports MySql.Data
Imports XXXXX.dataAccess.MySql

Public Shared Function CarregarEmpresas_grupo(Optional ByVal filtro As String = "", Optional ByVal ordem As String = "") As IDataReader
        Dim cn As MySqlConnection = Nothing
        Dim sql As String
        Dim comm As MySqlCommand = Nothing
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader

        Try
            cn = getConnection()
            If filtro <> "" Then filtro = " WHERE " & filtro
            If ordem <> "" Then ordem = " ORDER BY " & ordem
            sql = String.Format(EMPRESAS_GRUPO_SELECTALL, filtro, ordem)
            comm = New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)
            comm.CommandType = TipoComando
            reader = comm.ExecuteReader()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception("Erro a obter dados da base de dados: " & ex.Message, ex)
        Finally
            If cn.State = Data.ConnectionState.Open Then
                cn.Close()
                cn.Dispose()
            End If
        End Try

        Return reader
    End Function
```

(XXXXX.dataAccess.MySql is obfuscated by confidentiality matters)

And a screenshot of the error:
[image]

The error that displays Line28 is the equivalent of line 5 in the sample code I gave.
So given this, can anyone help? It's really a strange problem being abe to 'Go to definition' and open up everything correctly in Object Browser and not getting a single error during build but once the application is started get these errors.

Comment: A bit of code that demonstrates the problem will be useful

Comment: @Steve, I hope the new info helps :)

Comment: Did you add the reference to MySql.Data.dll in the references of your projects? (I mean, right click on Project References, Add references, Browse to MySql.Data.dll and check to add it to the project)

Comment: Yes that was done, and I even deleted now and re-added just in case, and I still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error by importing the "next level" of the MySQL.Data, specific to that error (MySQL.Data.Command I believe [it's been too long since I posted the question and fixes the error but I wanted to leave an answer in case anybody else faces this problem])